# How to set product image from base64 string?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to set product image with the write method but it doesnt work, what is the correct way to set product image in Odoo v9?

```
products = request.env['product.product'].search([],limit=10)
        for p in products:
                imagen = 'base64string'
                p.write({'imagen': imagen,})
```

[edit]
it was a typo error, I put 'imagen' insted of 'image'

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set it via xml file as written in product module in v9:

```
<field name="image" type="base64" file="product/static/img/product_product_1-image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to change it by a controller view, I need to set it and to be able to modify it later... xml dont work in this case